Tried making a "poor man's" active/MOSFET rectifier. It doesn't work, and I didn't expect it to, but I don't understand why
I attempted to design and assemble a "poor man's" 3-phase AC rectifier that uses MOSFETs without being driven by a gate driver.
The only thing driving the gates are the opposing phases.
In theory, for 3-phase AC, one phase can only be at its peak when the other two phases are opposite polarity. With this in mind, I assumed that the two opposing phases could be used to directly drive the gate of the corresponding MOSFET.
In order to keep each opposing phase isolated from each other, I used diodes so they wouldn't short to each other.
The function works like this:
3 MOSFETs are high-side, and 3 MOSFETs are low side.
The low MOSFETs open when their opposing phases are both high, allowing their gates to be pulled high by the 10k pull-up resistors.
The high MOSFETs open when their opposing phases are both low, allowing their gates to be pulled to ground by the 10k pull-down resistors.
For experimentation, I assembled a PCB according to the below diagram, and tested to see if it would or wouldn't work. It didn't work, but I don't understand why.
According to my oscilloscope, there was only about half a volt coming out the output, and had a big negative spike in the wave form too. I used a small 3 phase alternator to generate the signal and spun it with a drill; the first thing I noticed is that the alternator was loading up and difficult to turn, as if there was a short somewhere.
The real goal of this experiment was to see if it's possible to make a MOSFET rectifier without gate drivers or any other ICs.
Here's my schematic:


You'll definitely be exceeding the rated gate voltage on those FETs.

I'm not sure if @Rohat Kılıç's answer was entirely clear on the point, but the PFET symbols in your schematic are wrong.  They are showing body diodes from source (anode) to drain (cathode), but P-channel MOSFETs have body diodes from drain (anode) to source (cathode).  So, your circuit is basically shorting the alternator (e.g., when Phase 1 peaks and PFET1 is "on", PFET2 and PFET3 are forward conducting across their body diodes).

@K. A. Buhr that makes much more sense now! I was hesitant to reply to @ Rohat Kılıç for a while because I didn't understand how the body diode was facing the wrong way! Thanks for clearing it up. This is a good lesson and reminder to cross-check each and every symbol I use in KiCad; it certainly slipped me by.

If you want to build a MOSFET rectifier, you need to first arrange the circuit such that the rectification is done through the body diodes even when the MOSFETs are off. Keeping the MOSFETs off is easy: Place a resistor across the gate and source and don't apply any signal to the gates. Run the circuit and see the rectified output. Make sure the Vgs voltages during the operation do NOT exceed the maximum ratings. You may need Zener diodes otherwise.
Now if you look at the body diode arrangement of the PMOS you'll see they are wrong. This makes the entire circuit arrangement wrong. That's why your rectifier doesn't work.
I've build a MOSFET rectifier for single phase for you. Below is the sim schematic and the waveforms (Sorry, it's 8am in the morning here and I feel too lazy to modify the circuit for three phase so I'm leaving it to you.)


Green: Sinewave input (10 Vrms, 50 Hz), Dark blue: Vgs of M1, Light Blue: Vgs of M3, Red: Rectified output.
Note that I chose 10 Vrms to keep the Vgs of the MOSFETs within the ±20V range. You may need additional Zener diodes to limit the gate-source voltages if the input sine has higher amplitude.

You can replicate the circuit 3 times, then tie the outputs together. An issue though: the 3 phases cannot have a path to ground, nor can your single phase. Either the input is referenced to ground, or the output, but not both.

Also, adding capacitance to the output messes things up. This was my experience here:https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/208875/why-does-this-bridge-rectifier-claim-to-have-no-diode-forward-voltage-drop/649693#649693

@Rohat Kılıç thank you! I corrected the P channel FETs and also added zener diodes to ground for protecting the gates. As for the resistors, is it absolutely necessary to put a resistor between the gate and source? My circuit still has the 10k resistors connected to the output of the opposite FETs.

@soconnoriv a resistor across the gate-source ensures the off-state of the MOSFET in case the input becomes floating. Along with the gate stopper resistor (aka series gate resistor), it also works as a voltage divider. In your case there's a Zener so the effective series resistance will be the parallel of the aforementioned two resistors but still it's a good practice to keep the gate-source resistor.
